# Using Java 8 lambdas/transformations to combine and flatten two Maps

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have two maps:

- `Map<A, Collection<B>> mapAB`
- `Map<B, Collection<C>> mapBC`

I would like to transform them into a `Map<A, Collection<C>> mapAC` and I'm wondering if there's a smooth way to do that with lambdas and transformations. In my particular case, the collections are all sets, but I'd like to solve the problem for collections in general.

One thought I had was to first combine the two maps into a `Map<A, Map<B, Collection<C>>>` and then flatten it, but I'm open to any approach.

Data notes: `B` should only occur in the value collection associated with one `A`, and the same is true for `mapBC` (a given `C` is only mapped to from one `B`). As a result, there should only be one path from a given `A` to a given `C`, although there may be `A -> B` mappings for which there are no `B -> C` mappings and there may be `B -> C` mappings for which there are no corresponding `A -> B` mappings. These orphans simply don't appear in the resulting `mapAC`.

For the sake of comparison, here's an example of a purely imperative approach to the same problem:

```
Map<A, Collection<C>> mapAC = new HashMap<>();

for (Entry<A, Collection<B>> entry : mapAB.entrySet()) {
    Collection<C> cs = new HashSet<>();

    for (B b : entry.getValue()) {
        Collection<C> origCs = mapBC.get(b);
        if (origCs != null) {
            cs.addAll(origCs);
        }
    }

    if (!cs.isEmpty()) {
        mapAC.put(entry.getKey(), cs);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is what you want a join of two one-to-many relations without the middle column?

Comment: @MikeSamuel yeah, that's definitely one way to look at it.

Comment: Could you add example of data? For instance if we have `Map<Person, Set<Job>>` and `Map<Job, Set<Tool>>` is it possible for different people to have same job, or for few jobs use same tools? So is something like `p1 -> {j1, j2}, p2->{j2, j3}` possible? Also `job1->{tool1, tool2} job2->{tool2, tool3} job3->{tool4}`? What results you expect? Do you want also `Collection<X>` to be `Set` or can elements exist in it multiple time?

Comment: @Pshemo see the new "Data notes" section in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify what you would want to do if some b from the first map don't exist in the second map, so this may not be exactly what you are looking for.

```
mapAB.entrySet().stream()
  .filter(e -> e.getValue().stream().anyMatch(mapBC::containsKey))
  .collect(toMap(
       Map.Entry::getKey,
       e->e.getValue().stream()
           .filter(mapBC::containsKey)
           .map(mapBC::get)
           .flatMap(Collection::stream)
           .collect(toList())
  ));
```

Comment: By the way, you might want to mention that the code assumes you've statically imported `Collectors.toMap()` and `Collectors.toList()`. I'm happy to assume that you've also imported `Map.Entry`, so you could also drop the `Map.` prefix.

Comment: I was going to accept this answer, but then I wrote a unit test and discovered that if an entry in mapAB points to a Collection of Bs such that none of those Bs are keys in mapBC, you end up with an entry in mapAC pointing to an empty Collection. That's not the end of the world, but I was hoping to just have no entry in that case.

Comment: Adding the following filter before the outer collect does the trick, but it's rather ugly:

`filter(e -> !e.getValue().stream().filter(mapBC::containsKey).
                    collect(Collectors.toSet()).isEmpty())`

Comment: Or, more simply, `e->e.getValue().stream().anyMatch(mapBC::containsKey)`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a fan of the `forEach` approach, which is awkwardly imperative.  A purer approach might be

```
mapAB.entrySet().stream()
  .flatMap(
      entryAB -> entryAB.getValue().stream().flatMap(
          b -> mapBC.getOrDefault(b, Collections.<C>emptyList())
             .stream().map(
                 c -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(entryAB.getKey(), c))))
  // we now have a Stream<Entry<A, C>>
  .groupingBy(
     Entry::getKey,
     mapping(Entry::getValue, toList()));
```

...or maybe alternately

```
mapA.entrySet().stream()
  .flatMap(
      entryAB -> entryAB.getValue().stream().map(
          b -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(
              entryAB.getKey(), 
              mapBC.getOrDefault(b, Collections.<C>emptyList()))))
  // we now have a Stream<Entry<A, Collection<C>>>
  .groupingBy(
     Entry::getKey,
     mapping(Entry::getValue, 
       reducing(
          Collections.<C>emptyList(),
          (cs1, cs2) -> {
             List<C> merged = new ArrayList<>(cs1);
             merged.addAll(cs2);
             return merged;
          })));
```

Comment: I'm pondering your answer. The second version seems clever, but a bit hard to interpret. By the way, I've given the maps names (mapAB, mapBC). I'd edit your answer to use mapAB, but it only involves changing few enough chars that StackOverflow won't allow me to do it.

Comment: Updated for the variable names as well as your indication that `mapBC` may not contain all the Bs that appear in `mapAB`.

Answer (score 1):

My [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library provides an [`EntryStream`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/EntryStream.html) class which is stream of `Map.Entry` objects with some additional convenient operations. This is how I would solve this problem using my library:

```
Map<A, Collection<C>> mapAC = EntryStream.of(mapAB)
    .flatMapValues(Collection::stream) // flatten values: now elements are Entry<A, B>
    .mapValues(mapBC::get) // map only values: now elements are Entry<A, Collection<C>>
    .nonNullValues() // remove entries with null values
    .flatMapValues(Collection::stream) // flatten values again: now we have Entry<A, C>
    .groupingTo(HashSet::new); // group them to Map using HashSet as value collections
```

This probably less efficient as an excellent solution provided by @Misha as more intermediate objects are created, but to my opinion it's easier to write and understand this way.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
    Map<A, Collection<B>> mapAB = new HashMap<>();
    Map<B, Collection<C>> mapBC = new HashMap<>();
    Map<A, Collection<C>> mapAC = new HashMap<>();

    mapAB.entrySet().stream().forEach(a -> {
        Collection<C> cs = new HashSet<>();
        a.getValue().stream().filter(b -> mapBC.containsKey(b)).forEach(b -> cs.addAll(mapBC.get(b)));
        mapAC.put(a.getKey(), cs);
    });
```

Comment: This is definitely more compact than the imperative equivalent that I just added to the question, but it does have one flaw that I also initially failed to deal with in my example. Your call `mapB.get(b)` (which you could update to `mapBC` - see my naming updates above) could return null, so you need to deal with that.

Comment: You are correct, please review my edits... (added the filter)

Comment: Thanks for the edits. Unfortunately, it still exhibits the same behavior as Misha's answer, creating empty collections for B's that have no mapping in mapBC. See that answer's comments for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<A, Collection<C>> mapC =
    mapA.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
        entry -> entry.getKey(),
        entry -> entry.getValue().stream().flatMap(b -> mapB.get(b).stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toSet())));
```

Feel free to replace `Collectors.toSet()` with [toList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--), or even [toCollection()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toCollection-java.util.function.Supplier-).

Comment: I like the clarity in this approach, but see my question updates above. `mapB.get(b)` might return null, so you'll have to deal with that. Also see my updated variable naming.

Answer (score 0):

I actually have nothing against the imperative approach. Since you are collecting it into memory there is nothing to be gained by using lambdas really, unless they lead to cleaner code. Here the imperative approach is just fine:

```
Map<A, Collection<C>> mapAC = new HashMap<>();

for (A key : mapAB.keySet()) {
    Collection<C> cs = new HashSet<>();
    mapAC.put(key, cs);

    for (B b : mapAP.get(key)) {
        cs.addAll(mapBC.get(b)==null ?  Collections.emptyList() : mapBC.get(b));
    }
}
```

although I have in-lined your if statement as a ternary operator, and I think using the keys in the for loop looks clearer.

Comment: mapAB and mapBC could end up being pretty huge, so I would prefer to avoid extra lookups when possible. It's a shame that Java doesn't have [Groovy's Elvis operator](http://www.groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_elvis_operator), since that would be perfect as a substitute for your ternary expression, while avoiding the double lookup.